# How iterate condition checking in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, iteration

The following function gives the correct result for me. But for a large number of q's, it very difficult to handle this program.  So, I would like to iterate q's via a loop or some other manner. How can I do this?

```
def sgf(a): # here a is a list of two numbers
    import random
    a2=random.randint(1,1068)
    p=1069
    q1=(a[0]+a[1]*1+a2*1**2)%p
    q2=(a[0]+a[1]*2+a2*2**2)%p
    q3=(a[0]+a[1]*3+a2*3**2)%p
    q4=(a[0]+a[1]*4+a2*4**2)%p
    q5=(a[0]+a[1]*5+a2*5**2)%p
    q6=(a[0]+a[1]*6+a2*6**2)%p
    q7=(a[0]+a[1]*7+a2*7**2)%p
    q8=(a[0]+a[1]*8+a2*8**2)%p
    q9=(a[0]+a[1]*9+a2*9**2)%p
    while ((q1>1060) or (q2>1060) or (q3>1060) or (q4>1060) or (q5>1060) or (q6>1060) or (q7>1060) or (q8>1060) or (q9>1060)):
        a2=random.randint(1,1068)
        q1=(a[0]+a[1]*1+a2*1**2)%p
        q2=(a[0]+a[1]*2+a2*2**2)%p
        q3=(a[0]+a[1]*3+a2*3**2)%p
        q4=(a[0]+a[1]*4+a2*4**2)%p
        q5=(a[0]+a[1]*5+a2*5**2)%p
        q6=(a[0]+a[1]*6+a2*6**2)%p
        q7=(a[0]+a[1]*7+a2*7**2)%p
        q8=(a[0]+a[1]*8+a2*8**2)%p
        q9=(a[0]+a[1]*9+a2*9**2)%p
        if ((q1<=1060) and (q2<=1060) and (q3<=1060) and (q4<=1060) and (q5<=1060) and (q6<=1060) and (q7<=1060) and (q8<=1060) and (q9<=1060)):
            break  
    return q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6,q7,q8,q9
```

For simplicity,

```
f(x)=(a0+a1*x+a2*x**2)%p
```

where a0,a1 are in [0,1060] and a2 chosen randomly from [0,1068]
if all `f(x)<=1060`, accept f(x) otherwise regenerate f(x)

Comment: You should learn how to use lists and loops... In fact, for this particular problem, you should use NumPy.

Comment: Try something like `while any(a[0] + a[1] * 1 + a2 * i ** 2) % p > 1060 for i in range(1, 10))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the only variables in your generation of `q`s are the integers that you multiple `a[1]` and `a2` by.

You could alter your function to accept the total number of `q`s as a second parameter (e.g. `total_q`), then iterate over `range(1, total_q+1)` and append each new `q` to a Python list, returning the list at the end.

Try something like:

```
def sgf(a, total_q):
    import random
    a2=random.randint(1,1068)
    p=1069
    q_list = []
    for i in range(0,total_q+1):
        q = (a[0]+a[1]*i+a2*i**2)%p
        q_list.append(q)
    while any(q > 1060 for q in q_list):
        a2=random.randint(1,1068)
        q_list = []
        for i in range(0,total_q+1):
            q =(a[0]+a[1]*i+a2*i**2)%p
            q_list.append(q)

        if all(q <= 1060 for q in q_list):
            break 
    return q_list
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `q` should probably be a list. That way you can use a `for` loop with `range` to perform your calculation:

```
for ind in range(len(q)):
    q[ind]=(a[0]+a[1]*(ind + 1)+a2*(ind + 1)**2)%p
```

You can also represent your condition as an iteration, but the simplest way would probably be to use the `any` function and write your condition as a generator:

```
while any(qx > 1060 for qx in q):
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def sgf(a):
    import random
    a2=random.randint(1,1068)
    p=1069
    items = []
    # if items is empty, or any element is greater than 1060, keep looping
    while not items or any(item > 1060 for item in items):
        items = [(a[0]+a[1]*i+a2*i**2)%p for i in range(1,10)]
    return items
```